# "gpg: error reading key: No public key" when updating manjaro-keyring

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, gpg, pacman

I have a super weird issue which has almost been preventing me from installing/updating anything. Anytime pacman tries to update the `manjaro-keyring` package, I get the error in the title of this post. I have had to temporarily disable GPG checking in my `pacman.conf`, and I know this is not really an ideal security situation. Are there any known issues with the formatting on the GPG keys?

I'm running gnupg 2.2.29-1 and I've made sure to stay on the `stable` branch while the issue persists. I was on `unstable` but force downgraded everything. Rebooted and reregistered keys many times in multiple orders. I'm totally at a loss.

I've visited [Manjaro's help site](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Pacman_troubleshooting) and every Manjaro forum page that even mentions GPG. Suggestions from there unfortunately did nothing to help.

To be specific, on step 4: `sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux manjaro`

When it tries to append manjaro.gpg keys, I get the "No public key" error twice in a row, then the rest seems to continue normally. I tried continuing anyway, but when I re-enable key checking and run `sudo pacman -Syu` I get the following:

```
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                 171.2 KiB  32.2 KiB/s 00:05 [#####################################################################] 100%
 extra               1900.0 KiB  6.27 MiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
 community              6.7 MiB  8.44 MiB/s 00:01 [#####################################################################] 100%
 multilib             175.7 KiB  2.86 MiB/s 00:00 [#####################################################################] 100%
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
error: failed to synchronize all databases (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing everything afresh.

- Clear all keys, `sudo rm /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/*`.
- Install the keyring packages.
- Run `sudo pacman-key --init && sudo pacman-key --populate`

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the issue, though I've certainly seen it suggested for similar problems. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>After posting the question to Manjaro's forums, someone from the Manjaro team [responded](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/gpg-error-reading-key-no-public-key-when-updating-manjaro-keyring/86366/2?u=d1pl0mat) with the dead simple response of running `sudo rm -R /var/lib/pacman/sync`, then rebuilding mirrorlist and updating (`sudo pacman-mirrors -f5 && pacman -Syyu`). Somehow this did not come up looking anywhere else, but it appears that something in this directory was causing the issue.</strike>

I attempted an update about 4 hours later to verify this solution, and the error came back. What *has* worked so far instead is the solution in [this Manjaro forum thread](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/root-tip-mitigate-and-prevent-gpgme-error-when-syncing-your-system/84700). Specifically, I went into `/etc/pacman.conf` and replaced the existing `SigLevel` line with:

```
SigLevel = Required DatabaseNever
```

Comment: It looked as if it was a GPG key issue, and turns out it is about databases. Mark this answer as accepted.